# Return Specifc formatted data or more generic?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am playing around with the ASP.NET Web API and want to use it to feed data to my mobile apps (Android, iPhone, Windows Phone).

I am wondering though should I be returning data in more of a general way or more in a specific way.

I keep finding myself trying to send more specific data back but this might because I sort of an idea of how it would look on my mobile devices but not sure if this is a good way especially if I would ever open up my API to the public.

Example

I want to tell the user how many days ago the record was inserted into the database.

Is it better to calculate on the server that it was "5" and send them back and let them append "5 days ago" or is it better just to send a datetime back and let the device parse it (this would let them do anything to the date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific example, it's better to return the `DateTime` occurrence rather than an interpreted named delta.
Reasons:

- Time zones
- Globalisation

You would like to store this event as a UTC based timestamp in the database and let the clients calculate the difference, so they can show the accurate phrasing.
Unless you store all of your globalised strings centrally in the database, it makes more sense to have that on the client side as well.

Comment: Yes it would be UTC stored. How about in different situations. I am trying to determine when should I send back data in a specific way and when it is better to be more general and let the client side decide what to do with the raw data.

Comment: I think there's no silver bullet here. As in many cases; "It depends". Most likely you have to reason and judge every use case.